# What kind of stains/treatment/varnish do I need to make to my wooden door frame

Tags: wood, primer, sealer

I have an interior door frame, which has been sawn locally in Sumatra, Indonesia from what is referred to as 'damar'. This I suspect is Agathis borneensis, or possibly Agathis dammara.

I looked up the wood, and it suggests:

http://tropix.cirad.fr/FichiersComplementaires/EN/Asia/AGATHIS.pdf

'Susceptible to termites'

'Susceptible to dry wood insect borers'

'Poor to moderately durable to fungi'

'Treatability: good'

Apparently Chromated Copper Fluoride treatment will protect against borers and termites in local conditions:

http://www.fao.org/forestry/11703-06b5824b879201dab11d49a0288960124.pdf

So I guess I need to source that.

I would also like to stain the wood.

Can anyone tell me what kind of products are needed?

I understand that there are many, i.e. wood stain, primer, sealer and varnish.

What combination of products and in what order should I use?

Comment: Just a note: those notes apply I believe to European/French climate conditions. Here the dew point is around 25 Celsius, and the temperatures range between around 25-32 Celsius. So maybe there is some difference in terms of fungi, etc.

Comment: I found some further information, which suggests that (a) under Indonesian conditions, this wood is one of the most susceptible to termites of all woods, and (b) the building's concrete slab may prevent or inhibit termites.